# Tag wikis are incorrectly limited to 30,000 characters when editing them from the revision history

Tags: bug, edits, tag-wiki, revisions-list

#### Preparation

- You need the [Edit community wiki privilege (100 reputation)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), but the bug also occurs when you have the [Tag Wikis privilege (20,000 reputation)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).
- Find a tag with [a body of more than 30,000 characters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1063553/lengthy-tags), like [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), or be ready to submit a change of over 30,000 characters to some tag.

#### Scenario 1

- You visit the "<kbd>history</kbd>" of the tag.
- You "<kbd>edit</kbd>" from the tag revisions page. Add content to make it more than 30,000 characters.
- You attempt to "<kbd>Save Edits</kbd>".

Result of scenario 1 is an error:

> Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 40519.

#### Scenario 2

- You "<kbd>Edit Tag Info</kbd>" on the wiki of the tag. Add content to make it more than 30,000 characters.
- You attempt to "<kbd>Save Edits</kbd>".

Result of scenario 2 is a success: either as an edit or as a submission for review (demonstration: [this is a 33,491 characters long suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4913043/96)).

#### Conclusion

The length limitation is not applied consistently.

Comment: [Machavity](/users/244695/machavity) wrote "[Wikis cannot exceed 30k chars now](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607050/471)".